# ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> in Power BI

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, powerbi, train-test-split

im facing following problem by trying to train a ML model.

```
Error Message:
Ρýтнбл ѕ¢řїрŧ ëřřбŕ.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 36, in <module>
    model.fit(train.drop('Demand', axis=1), train.Demand)
  File "C:\Users\ekurt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4139, in drop
    errors=errors,
  File "C:\Users\ekurt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3923, in drop
    axis_name = self._get_axis_name(axis)
  File "C:\Users\ekurt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 420, in _get_axis_name
    raise ValueError(f"No axis named {axis} for object type {cls}")
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Im trying to run this in Power BI with Python script. 
I would be glad if someone can help me with this issue.

Let me know if you need further information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should post a code snippet that raises the exception

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np 

dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Demand, Date, Temperature)

dataset['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'])
dataset.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
dataset = dataset.resample('W').sum()#.ffill()
dataset.index.freq = 'W'

train, test = dataset.iloc[:300, 0], dataset.iloc[300:, 0]
#X_train = train.drop('Demand', axis=1)
#X_test = test.drop('Demand', axis=1)
#y_train = train.Demand
#y_test = test.Demand

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(train.drop('Demand', axis=1), train.Demand)
```

Ok, i solved it by deleting the [0] in

```
train, test = dataset.iloc[:300, 0], dataset.iloc[300:,0]
```

in

```
train, test = dataset.iloc[:300], dataset.iloc[300:]
```